# Trying to deploy a create-react-app project to Netlify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory, netlify

My current project is having trouble building in the Netlify platform. I am able to build my app locally just fine and host it through gh-pages, but when I try to build the same app, I run into this error.

[Netlify Deploy Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDtzw.png)

```
11:10:03 PM: Failed to compile.
11:10:03 PM: 
11:10:03 PM: ./src/pages/Mortgage.js
11:10:03 PM: Cannot find file '../hooks/UseWindowSize.js' in './src/pages'.
```

[Current Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4LCx.png)

```
src
--hooks
----UseWindowSize.js
--pages
----Home.js
----Mortgage.js
```

Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't building on your dev machine then pushing that to Netlify? Might be easier depending on situation.

Comment: This is my first time using Netlify and I was interested in using their auto deploy upon git repo changes, I'll look into just uploading the build folder directly. Though I would like to understand why it is not working in the first place.

Comment: Could you please share the link of the repo here (if it's public)? It will help to debug. @Sirivs

Comment: Based on the error messages one possible problem is the path through the file structure is different based on which directory you are running the build command from which is changed by Netlify. Maybe use node's path.join with __dirname https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-how-to-use__dirname

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to get it working.

I added the site on `Netlify` by linking it via a `Github` repository. Then inside on Netlify, I did the flowing:

1. Click on the `Sites` menu link and select the site you would like to deploy
2. To access the `Settings`, click on either:

   - The `Site Settings` button - is located in the first block/widget below the menu
   - `Deploys` in the menu next to `Site Overview` then click the `Deploy setting` button - located in the first block/widget below the menu
3. Below the first block/widget click the link `Build & deploy` -
   located in the left side navigation aside
4. In the `Build settings` widget block, click the `Edit settings` button.

   - Change `Base directory` to `./`
   - Change `Build command` to `npm run build`
   - Change `Publish directory` to `./build`
5. Scroll down to `Environment variables` and add the key `PRODUCTION`, set the value of `PRODUCTION` to `true`

Retry your build to see if the configuration worked.

Side note: It's a `fresh create react app react install`, no 3rd party librarys yet.

Happy Coding =)

**Pro Tip - create a `netlify.toml` file in the root of your project and add the following:**

```
# Production context:
# All deploys from the main repository branch
# will inherit these settings.
[context.production]
  command = "npm run build"
  [context.production.environment]
    PRODUCTION = "true"
```

Ive noticed that using a boolean value as a string works but if you use it like normal the build breaks

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, using Vercel with React is way easier, and it's also better.
Push project onto a repository, go to vercel's site, login with Github, and choose your repository and it does 95% for you.
Netlify also has some problems with React-router, so Vercel is over all a clear winner.

Comment: This question was asked for `Netlify`. While using an alternative like `Vercel` would definitely work, what if your can't change the design architecture due to some restraint. Because if 3rd party packages  are an issue there its best you find packages that work or you create a simple flow to route your application using a Global State Provider coupled with a Consumer - Create react App has documentation that helps solve "Basic functionality" when you need to deal with routing and `Netlify` has template solutions that include routing so you could use that to get an idea of how to achieve this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).